# Angular JS ui-router how to redirect to a child state from a parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using onEnter to redirect to a state, if the new state is a child of the current state, an infinite loop occurs.

**Example:**

```
$stateProvider
  .state 'inventory',
    url: '/inventory'
    templateUrl: 'views/inventory.html'
    controller: 'InventoryCtrl'
    onEnter: () ->
      $state.go 'inventory.low'
  .state 'inventory.low',
    url: '/low'
    templateUrl: 'views/inventory-table.html'
    controller: 'LowInventoryCtrl'
```

When:

```
$state.go 'inventory.low'
```

**Is called, the state `inventory` is re-initialized, causing it to be called again = infinite loop.**

However, if the redirect state is:

```
$state.go 'otherStateThatIsNotAChild'
```

This issue does not occur. I assume that the parent state is being re-initialized, but why?

1. Why is the parent state being reinitialized when `.go` is called on a child state?
2. How then, would you handle redirecting to a child state?

Comment: TaylorMac, see my edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1) Why is the parent state being reinitialized when .go is called on a
>   child state?

While a transition is in process, any $state.go/transitionTo will cause the *currently in process* transition to be Superseded. An in-process transition that is superseded is cancelled immediately.  Since your original transition to `inventory` is not completed by the time all the states' onEnters are called, the original transition is cancelled and a *new* transition to `inventory.low` is started from the previously active state.

See ui-router src https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L897 ...

> 2) How then, would you handle redirecting to a child state?

You could...

- Wrap `$state.go` in a `$timeout()` to allow the original transition to complete before redirecting.
- Call $state.go from your controller instead.  UI-router invokes the controller from the ui-view directive AFTER the transition is completed.

In any case, be very sure you want your app to redirect like this.  If a user navigated directly to any other child state of inventory (such as `inventory.high`), the redirect will still occur, forcing them to `inventory.low` which would not be what they intended.

Comment: For 1), great - that answers the question. It is Not that it is reinitialized because it is redirecting to a child state (which is what I thought was weird) it is because the state transition is not complete. And good point about transitioning to .low in child states - I didn't even think about that. Perhaps listening for $stateChangeStart on 'inventory', is the best approach. Kudos!

Comment: See also my pet project, ui-router-extras.  It has a feature called DeepStateRedirect which may do what you want.  It indeed listens to $stateChangeStart on, e.g., 'inventory':  http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/dsr/index.html#/

Comment: Aside from watching $stateChangeStart, you can also do this in the controller with an if checking $state.current.name, so the redirection only happens when you're on the parent state.

Comment: Or you could define a `redirectTo` property on the parent state object, redirecting it to a child state. This supposed will ensure the parent state is completed before the redirect. See an example of this in [ui-router's own example](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app/blob/master/app/app.state.js)[https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app/blob/master/app/app.state.js](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app/blob/master/app/app.state.js). ```let appState = {
  name: 'app',
  redirectTo: 'welcome',
  template: template,
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. The simple solution I found is to listen state changes and redirect to your child state from there.

It's kind of hack that makes routes redirecting to child states by default. **It's not needed to do** `url: ''` or `$state.go()`, they don't work correctly.

So, in `config` file:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
  if (toState.redirectTo) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go(toState.redirectTo, toParams);
  }
});
```

In `state` file:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '',
  redirectTo: 'home.list'
});
```

I've made an example on gist: https://gist.github.com/nikoloza/4ab3a94a3c6511bb1dac

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to step back and think about what you're trying to achieve. What's the point of having a state when all it's doing is redirecting to a child state?

Regarding your first question, parent states are always activated when you arrive at a child state, this behaviour is extremely useful in sharing data among states, and without it nested routing would be impossible (or rather wouldn't make sense).

As for the 2nd question, I've worked on a few big angular apps and so far I haven't found myself needing to do that.

OK, believe it or not, as much I'd hate to say it, right now I came across a scenario where I needed to do this. I have a `profile/userName` route (technically this should be `profile/userName/details`) and a `profile/userName/products` route, I wanted to have a master view for both states but at the same time I wanted the `profile/userName` route have a clean url, like: `profile/mike62`, NOT `profile/mike62/details`. So I ended up doing this:

```
.state('publicProfile', { url: '/profile/{username}'})//this is the base/shell state
.state('publicProfile.details',{url:null})//I want this to be my de-facto state, with a clean URL, hence the null url
.state('publicProfile.products', {url:'/products/{exceptProductId:/?.*}'})
```

Ended up achieving it like this, there are many ways though:

in my `publicProfile` state controller (this is the base state):

```
$scope.state = $state;
$scope.$watch('state.current', function(v) {
       if(v.name=='publicProfile') {//want to navigate to the 'preferred' state if not going to publicProfile.products
            $state.go('publicProfile.details');
       };
}, true);
```

Yes, it does feel hacky but now I know that there are some edge cases where we want to do this, althopugh we could rethink our state design altogether. Another, dirtier way would be to check the current state in a $timeout with a small delay inside the base state, if we are not on the `publicProfile.products` state, we navigate to our preferred/de-facto state of `publicProfile.details`.

Comment: My thoughts on this are: 1) why wouldn't you just respond to the $stateChangeStart event, rather than making the model observable? I understand the usefulness for augmenting $rootScope with $state for use within the template, but observing a property on the template and correlating this with a state? I don't know if this is much better than putting in the controller, where it is at least localized

Comment: the scenario you described is indeed the need for this, and is much used when you think in hierarchical modularizations

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to set a default child state.

That's a commonly asked question about ui-router: [How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)

The tl;dr is to use [abstract states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states) by settings `abstract: true` in the parent state. If you add multiple child states, it'll default to first child state.

```
$stateProvider

  .state('inventory', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/inventory',
    templateUrl: 'views/inventory.html',
    controller: 'InventoryCtrl'
  }).

    .state('inventory.low', {
      url: '/low',
      templateUrl: 'views/inventory-table.html',
      controller: 'LowInventoryCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: Hey @Atav32 does this still work? I tried to do what the FAQ said but I still get an "Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'parent'" after clicking my ui-sref="parent".

Comment: @Exegesis Hmm, I haven't tried linking to the parent state. I just directly link to the "default" child. `ui-sref="parent.child"`

Comment: wow, this seems the right way to go! Nice ref, too. My only fear is using gulp, don't know who will be the first child state.. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Z.Khullah could you explain how Gulp might interfere?

Comment: Found it, as per the reference you can use **empty URL** to set who the default is, or as found in [discussions](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/497) you can use **redirectTo** to define+redirect automatically. The last also solves @Exegesis question, in [this specific thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2255).

Comment: @Atav32 gulp (using libraries like FUSE) will concatenate all js files into one, following the tree sctructure and probably alphabetical order of files and folders. So module A would be declared first than module B, which could be the wanted default.

Answer (score 2):

Per pdvorchik's answer on the [related GitHub thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1434), there is a simple fix for this which worked perfectly for me, consisting of wrapping the `$state.go` call in a `.finally()` call to make sure the first transition completes before a new one is started.

```
onEnter: ['$state', function($state){
    if ($state.transition) {
        $state.transition.finally(function() {
            $state.go('home.my.other.state', {})
        });
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

After @Chris T's explanation, it seems that the cleanest solution is to listen for the `$stateChangeSuccess` event:

```
redirects =
  inventory: 'inventory.low'

$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeSuccess', (e, toState) ->
  redirect = redirects[toState.name]
  $state.go redirect if redirect
```

Where redirects will contain any route redirects that may occur. Thanks all!

Comment: Personally, I'd hook it into $stateChangeStart, and if there's a redirect, run e.preventDefault() to cancel the transition before performing the redirect.

Comment: Yes I agree with that, this is what I implemented

Answer (score -1):

Don't make the low inventory state a child state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state 'inventory',
        url: '/inventory'
        templateUrl: 'views/inventory.html'
        controller: 'InventoryCtrl'
        onEnter: () ->
            $state.go 'lowinventory'
    .state 'lowinventory',
        url: '/inventory/low'
        templateUrl: 'views/inventory-table.html'
        controller: 'LowInventoryCtrl'
```

Comment: Right, but then it won't resolve the promises of the parent states map object, or inherit data, and it won't load into the ui-view of the inventory state's template, which is the whole point