# When routing to a nested UI-router-state, how can I inspect which nested state will be called from the parent?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the Angular UI-router module to navigate to a nested state.

I have a state called `program`, and a state called `program.dashboard`.

Whenever a user routes to `program` (without providing a nested route), it should redirect to `program.dashboard`.  How can I tell from within the state whether it's on it's way to a nested route?

The problem I'm running into presently is that routing to any nested route under `program` is causing a redirect to `program.dashboard` because when the program route is evaluated, it knows nothing of the child route that is still to be loaded.

Here's something similar where the answer details the issue I'm having. They point out that you'll never be able to navigate to any state under `program` other than `program.dashboard`, which is exactly why I want to check to see where it's going and conditionally redirect. [Angular JS ui-router how to redirect to a child state from a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977366/1070412)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
.state('program', {
            url: "/program/{programId:[0-9]{1,8}}",
            templateUrl: "components-child",
            controller: function($scope, $rootScope, orgService, $state, 
            $stateParams) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.curentOrganization = null;
                vm.currentProgram = null;

                $scope.$watch(function() {
                        return orgService.currentProgram();
                    },
                    function(newVal, oldVal) {
                        if (newVal != null) {
                             //this causes a redirect to program.dashboard
                             //even if I want to go to..say.. program.settings
                            $state.go('program.dashboard', 
                                 { programId: newVal.programId });

                            vm.currentProgram = newVal;
                        }
                    }, true);

            },
            params: { programId: { value: '{{currentProgram.programId}}' } },
        })
.state('program.dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "dashboard-dashboard",
            controller: 'DashboardController as vm',
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, you probably want to listen for $stateChangeStart, not watch a service value.

```
app.run(function($state, $rootScope) { 
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.name === 'program') {
      // this is a transition directly to 'program'
      event.preventDefault(); // cancel the transition
      $state.go('program.dashboard', toParams); // push them to 'program.dashboard'
    }
  });
});
```