# AngularJS ui-router default state for states without a URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have a couple of states for one page, so the states don't have any URL assigned to them. Is there a way to specify a default state for URL-less states? Maybe similar to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`.

I tried going to a state in Angular's `run` statement or within the controller but that causes a `transition superseded` error, which is probably due to the fact that `$state` hasn't been initialized.

Below is a short example. I would like to start directly in `stateA`.

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('stateA', {
          controller: function () {
            // Do some magic related to state A
          }
        })
        .state('stateB', {
          controller: function () {
            // Do some magic related to state B
          }
        });
    }
  ])
  .controller(['$state', '$timeout', function($state, $timeout){
    // My global controller
    // To set a default state I could do:
    // $timout(function () {
    //   $state.go('stateA'); 
    // }, 0);
    // But that doesn't feel right to me.
  }]);
```

**Update**:
Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977366/981933) I figured out that I have to wrap `$state.go` into a `$timeout`, to avoid the `transition superseded` error.

Comment: Isn't that what `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` does?

Comment: I thought its for specifying a default URL. Hence its name.

Comment: It should take your app to that state (`/` in this case) if no route matches

Comment: I too have this question. I am working in an embedded application that cannot use, modify, or rely on the URL in any way but I want a default state. ```$urlRouterProvider.otherwise``` doesn't seem right for this use-case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will call a [custom rule](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) that goes to a default state without tampering with a URL.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $state.go('stateA');
});`
```