# Navigating to a child state refreshes its parent state too

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'll try to provide a sample pseudo-code to be able to explain my issue as detailed as possible. I wouldn't be able to put here a working code because there're too many layers, directives and templates involved there.

My basic structure is:

```
...
<div>
   <div ui-view>
       <div ui-view></div>
   </div>
</div>
...
```

When the code within parent `ui-view` does a `$state.go` to update child `ui-view`, the parent is also loaded again.

Let's say the parent state is called `contact` and child one is `details`. My `$state.go` call is `$state.go("contact.details")`, and the `$stateProvider` configuration would look as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state({ name: "contact" /*,  rest of properties */ });
$stateProvider.state({ name: "contact.details", /*,  rest of properties */ });
```

Furthermore, the whole child `ui-view` happens within a directive transclusion. Let's say that it would be:

```
<div>
   <div ui-view>
       <directive>
           <content>
                <div ui-view></div>
           </content>
       </directive>
   </div>
</div>
```

With these details, do you detect any issue? Why `$state.go("contact.details")` reload `contact` too? (Note that `contact.details` is loaded, but reloading `contact` has side-effects because the controller is executed again...).

### Update

If I call `$state.go("details")` on `contact`'s controller, it happens the same issue, but once this is loaded, when I `$state.go` to other substates, each child state is opened as expected, **but parent state's controller is called again**.

Comment: why are you using two unamed `uiView` directives??

Comment: @Hitmands Well, they're unmaned but are part of different states

Comment: @Hitmands See that I said the second and child ui-view is the content of some directive transclusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the problem but i have a difference with you, my parent state is either abstract or either redirect to a default child in his controller.

So i would have

```
$stateProvider.state({ name: "contact" /*,  rest of properties */ 
      controller:['$state', function($state){
         if($state.current.name=='contact'){
              $state.go('contact.main');
         }
      }]
 });
$stateProvider.state({ name: "contact.main", /*,  rest of properties */ 
$stateProvider.state({ name: "contact.details", /*,  rest of properties */ });
```

Comment: I'm all check this tomorrow. BTW, this is what I already do (see my update updated question)

Comment: While it didn't provide any value so far, I've advanced on solving my issue. BTW, the last frontier to fix my problem is that when I go to the child state, the equivalent to `contact`'s controller is called all over again whenever I change to a child state.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out how to solve my issue/scenario.

1. I've switched to register substates using the *dot syntax* as first argument. For example `$stateProvider.state("a.b", {})` instead of `$stateProvider.state({ name: "b", parent: "a" });`. I know that my question says I was registering states using `name: "a.b"`. I've changed my code many times since I published this Q&A.
2. I'm now calling `$state.go("a.b")` in substate's `controller` to open a default child state (this is the root of the issue). See [Angular JS ui-router how to redirect to a child state from a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960288/angular-js-ui-router-how-to-redirect-to-a-child-state-from-a-parent) and